# how to bind event with sqldependency and unsubscribe in c#

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler, sqldependency

i have problem to bind event with custom parameter, its not unsubscribe while subscribe next time. basically when 1st time subscribe event, its hold the 1st event and make new event when 2nd time subscribe. mean there are 2 events and 3rd time there will be 3 events and so on. but i need 1 event only each time while subscribe and unsubcribe last event.

> 1. dependency_Update function

```
public void dependency_Update(Guid clientid)
{
    SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL.newemailmessagescountbyclient_sql(), connection))
    {
       connection.Open();
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@clientid", clientid));
       command.Notification = null;
       SqlDependency.Start(connString);
       SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
       dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler((s, e) => dependency_OnChange(s, e, dependency, clientid));
       dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler((s, e) => dependency_OnChange(s, e, dependency, clientid));
       var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
       connection.Close();

     }
 }
```

> 2. dependency_OnChange event

```
public void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e, SqlDependency dependency, Guid clientid)
{
   if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
   {
     //subscribe function again
     dependency_Update(clientid);
   }
}
```

can any one have solution for that, please help me, i appreciate your valuable time, thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? "its not unsubscribe while subscribe next time" is not very clear. What you expect, what goes wrong?

Comment: @Evk thanks for your response, i just update question,

Answer (score 0):

This block

```
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler((s, e) => dependency_OnChange(s, e, dependency, clientid));
dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler((s, e) => dependency_OnChange(s, e, dependency, clientid));
```

Doesn't do anything useful. First, its intention is strange - you are trying to subscribe and immediately unsubscribe. Second, it doesn't work as expected, because, despite looking the same - your two anonymous function handlers are different. In effect - you never really unsubscribe your handler from `OnChange` event. If you want to use anonymoys function, do it like that:

```
SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
OnChangeEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s, e) => dependency_OnChange(s, e, clientid, handler);
dependency.OnChange += handler;

public void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e, Guid clientid, OnChangeEventHandler handler) {
    var dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change) {
        dependency.OnChange -= handler;
        //subscribe function again
        dependency_Update(clientid);
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
OnChangeEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s, e) => {
      dependency.OnChange -= handler;
      dependency_OnChange(s, e, clientid);                    
};
dependency.OnChange += handler;
```

Comment: again i have the same problem by using both way.

Comment: can you plz see there what problem can be, because i have again the same problem. thanks

Comment: @adnan how exactly you see there is the same problem? How do you test?

Comment: because on logout the app, i just stop sqldependency and start again when login app, but again the same problem as i have already mean, its doest not unsubscribe the event, and its hold all event after logout the app, and how many times we login or logout its call number of time the dependency event. thanks